# Whenever I open terminal I get 'bash: export: `/home/shameen:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin': not a valid identifier'

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, directory, export

Even after restarting,as soon as I open terminal on the top I get this

```
bash: export: `/home/shameen:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin': not a valid identifier
bash: ./bashrc: No such file or directory
```

Any idea how can I remove this error?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gSM9.png)

Comment: Hello, welcome on SO. Please do not use images to show plain text messages. Just copy-paste them and format as code blocks. Do you have a `.bashrc` (not `./bashrc`) file in your home directory? If yes it may be the cause of your problem. Open it and look for an `export` command. Search also for the `./bashrc` string. Look also, maybe, at `.profile` or `.bash_profile`, still in your home directory, they are other `bash` configuration files.

Comment: In order to quickly find the culprit you can also temporarily rename these files: `mkdir -p ~/tmp` to create a `tmp` subdirectory in your home. Then: `mv ~/.bashrc ~/tmp` and open a new terminal. If the errors are still there it wasn't this one; restore: `mv ~/tmp/.bashrc ~` and try with the next on the list.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing what's actually in your startup/resource files (eg, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, etc) we can only guess.

For the 2nd error message re: `./bashrc`, Renaud Pacalet has already addressed this one ... incorrect reference of the `bashrc` file:

```
wrong: ./bashrc
right: .bashrc (or ~/.bashrc)
```

I'm guessing you have something like:

```
. ./bashrc            # or
source ./bashrc
```

which should be:

```
. .bashrc             # or
source .bashrc        # or
. ~/.bashrc           # or
source ~/.bashrc
```

---

For the 1st error message I'm guessing you've populated a variable (eg, `PATH`) and incorrectly `export`ed this variable:

```
wrong: export $PATH    # contents of PATH variable are exported
right: export PATH     # variable is exported
```

Example:

```
$ x='/home/shameen:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin'

$ export x
$ 
    # no output, just a new prompt; this means the variable was successfully exported

$ export $x
-bash: export: `/home/shameen:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin': not a valid identifier
    # attempt to 'export' the contents of variable 'x' => same error message you're receiving
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I think I found the second error 
 `"source ./bashrc" >> ~/.bashrc`, as for the first one I am not sure that where it went wrong, if it's not too much then can you please take a look at this `"export $HOME:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin" >> ~/.bashrc`
 `"export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin" >> ~/.bashrc`
It is just that I tried to download a bioinformatics tool which was PanRV [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/panrv2/files/) through its installer. Plus I am really new to the languages which is why my question might be a bit too basic. Still thank you so much

Comment: @shameenanwar please update the question with the complete command(s) you're using to populate `~/.bashrc`; are you really issuing `"export $HOME:..."` or are you issuing `echo "export $HOME:..."`?  also, why are you (dynamically) creating `.bashrc`? there are several possible issues here but addressing these issues will depend on you providing **exactly** what your running